# getting error not all code paths return value by c# compiler

Tags: c#, string, exception, compilation

This is a basic string reverse program and I want to do some level of exception handling in it. But during compilation it gives me an error "NOt all code paths return value. I am not able to find out why

```
 public static string Reverse(string s)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                {
                    throw new NullReferenceException();
                }

                char[] c = s.ToCharArray();
                int start = 0;
                int end = c.Length - 1;
                char temp;

                while (start < end)
                {
                    temp = c[start];
                    c[start] = c[end];
                    c[end] = temp;
                    start++;
                    end--;
                }
                return new string(c);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Thanks guys...I change the code to something like this

```
 public static string Reverse(string s)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            {
                char[] c = s.ToCharArray();
                int start = 0;
                int end = c.Length - 1;
                char temp;

                while (start < end)
                {
                    temp = c[start];
                    c[start] = c[end];
                    c[end] = temp;
                    start++;
                    end--;
                }
                return new string(c);
            }
            else return s;


        }
```

Comment: Small critique on your 2nd version: If the parameter is null you should either throw or return an empty string. Propagating null isn't very useful (in this situation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an exception happens then there is no return statement being executed. Walk it through.

The best remedy (my choice) would be to remove the entire try/catch . A utility function like Reverse should not handle (its own) exceptions.

Comment: so where should I handle condition for null and empty strings?

Comment: @Learner: I answered that below

Comment: Learner, Revers checks it argument (OK) but it should not handle (consume) that error by it self. It is a signal to the code (caller) that supplied the bad argument. And where does Console.Writeline go in an ASP.NET or Windows program? Reverse should not assume anything about the application type.

Answer (score 4):

If you throw an exception before the return statement, the `catch` handler is called. After the catch handler executes, it procedes past it (since there's no `return` or `throw` statement in it), at which point it reaches the end of the method without returning a value.

**Edit 2 (major bug):** You throw an `ArgumentNullException`, and procede to catch it and "eat" it, so it's pointless (in this form). You should do your parameter validation before entering a `try` block, plus this method shouldn't use a `try` block at all (it'll make it slower for no useful reason).

Edit: on a side note:

```
char[] characters = s.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(characters);
return new string(characters);
```

Comment: The try block does not make it slower.

Comment: It makes it less likely for the X64 JIT to produce fully optimal code from it. (can't find the link I was after and I have to run to see HP!)

Comment: +1, Using `Array.Reverse` is cleaner *and* faster than any of the other suggestions. (Well, it was quicker in a handful of quick-and-dirty benchmarks that I just tried.)

Answer (score 2):

You have to return a string from the `catch` clause as well as from the `try` clause (either that, or raise some exception) -- right now you don't have a `return` in your `catch` clause.

Answer (score 2):

In your catch block you either need to return a string or throw an exception.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is add a "throw;" line after your Console.WriteLine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real question is how do you want to handle an inputted null or empty string. If you believe your method should handle this by silently "correcting", you can return String.Empty. If however, you believe the calling methods should deal with this error, then throwing an exception and not catching it seems like the appropriate course of action. Regardless of which you choose it seems you shouldn't need the try/catch block.

```
public static string Reverse(string s)
{
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
     {
          //option 1
          return String.Empty;
          //option 2
          throw new NullReferenceException();
     }
     //rest of method
}
```

Comment: I would return String.Empty, there is nothing principally wrong with asking for the reverse of an empty string. You might want to treat null differently though.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way of doing it might be as follows

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string reverseMe = "hello world";
    string reversed = ReverseString(reverseMe);
    Console.WriteLine(reversed);
}

private static string ReverseString(string reverseMe)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(reverseMe)) return String.Empty;
    char[] reverseMeArray = reverseMe.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(reverseMeArray);
    string result = new string(reverseMeArray);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1, Using `Array.Reverse` is cleaner *and* faster than any of the other suggestions. (Well, it was quicker in a handful of quick-and-dirty benchmarks that I just tried.)