# Error in C#(windows 8.1 phojne development)

Tags: c#

I am new to program language ,i can't locate what is my problem ,i looked through some of the help pages provided in this community,but i can't find the solution..

Here is my question?

I trying to parse a JsonArray which i am  getting from my webserver..
My parsing code is this,But it gives me the error which i mentioned below

```
private async void NavigateBtn_Click1(object sender, RoutedE..ventArgs e)
    {
       long phone = System.Convert.ToInt64(phoneNumber.Text);
       string pwd = System.Convert.ToString(passWord.Text);
       Uri url = new Uri("http://www.example.com&phNum=" + phone + "&pass=" + pwd);
           System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
           var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
           var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           Debug.WriteLine(result);
           Login deserializedUser = ReadToObject(result);
           Frame.Navigate(typeof(Maps));
        }
    }
    private  static  Login ReadToObject(string resul)
          {
            TakeUz.Login.User.RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TakeUz.Login.User.RootObject>(resul);     // deserializing
               // var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TakeUz.Login.User.RootObject>();
                foreach (var blog in obj.User)
               {
                  Debug.WriteLine(blog.Version);
                   Debug.WriteLine(blog.Vuser);
               }

              //  Login deserializedUser = new Login();
               // MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
               // DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(deserializedUser.GetType());
                //deserializedUser = ser.ReadObject(ms) as Login;
               // ms.Dispose();
                //return deserializedUser;
            }

    }
```

My Json Deserializable code is

```
class Login
{
     [DataContract]
    public class User
    {
         [DataMember]
        public float Version { get; set; }
         [DataMember]
        public string Vuser { get; set; }
          [DataMember]
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
          [DataMember]
        public string Hd { get; set;}
         [DataMember]
        public string Verify { get; set; }
          [DataMember]
        public Int32 key { get; set; }

        public class RootObject
        {
             public List<User> User { get; set; }
            // public int success { get; set; }
         }
```

And my jsoncode is

> [{"rV":1.2,"VerifiedUser":"test","ID":"1234","HD":"LI","Verify":"NEWUSER","key":"1234"}]

It returns me a error

> "Not all code paths return a value"

Help me ,I'm struck in it

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting error not all code paths return value by c# compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148218/getting-error-not-all-code-paths-return-value-by-c-sharp-compiler)

Answer (score 0):

Your method `ReadToObject`, which should return a `Login`, has obviously no `return`statement. It's only in a comment:

```
//return deserializedUser;
```

UPDATE:

The brackets of your code snippet don't match. You have 3 opening brackets `{` and 5 closing `}`. I.e. the code blocks are not grouped as you expected. This can cause your error.

Comment: if i use return deserializedUser,it says    "cannot implicitly type convert type from " takeuz.login.RootObject"  to "Takeuz.Login"

Comment: (1) Does your error also occour if you un-comment `//  Login deserializedUser = new Login();` and `//return deserializedUser;` (2) also un-commenting the other lines in between will give a compile error because the variable `json`is undefined.

Comment: jimijoe:if i uncomment the lines you said and comment the lines before it ,it gives me a error like this,"A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL"

Comment: Can you add the json code your are deserializing to your question?